# Animation only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

There is a small problem with my javascript code. The animate fucntion only works once when I click on .add-case. Still the alert within the 'on' function show every time.

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-case', function(){
    height = $('.filling').height(); 
    alert('Works') // This shows every time I click
    $('.filling').animate({ height: $(this).height() + 40}, 600); 
    // this only works once
});
```

Anyone that could help?

Comment: `this` isn't what you expected it to be, i guess... Now try instead: `height: "+=40"`

Comment: @A.Wolff, If `this` was the issue then how could it work once ?

Comment: @RayonDabre I guess OP had a wrong observation

Comment: @RayonDabre For first click, `$(this).height()` will be something and adding `40` to it will animate the element, for clicks onwards the same height is get and the height is set to the same. Ex. first click => `20 + 40` set height => `60`. For next click => `20 + 40`, set height => `60`.

Comment: @Tushar, Now this is something... **Nice Observation:P**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem here is the `height` of the clicked element is not changed on click. So, on every click the same height is retrieved and updated.

```
$(this).height()
```

will get the height of the **clicked element**. `$(this)` inside the event handler is the jQuery object of the element on which the event occurred.

**Solution:**

Use relative size `+=40` to increase the height by 40. Although, `$(elementSelector).height() + 40` can also be used, but it's better to use relative units.

> Animated properties can also be relative. If a value is supplied with a leading += or -= sequence of characters, then the target value is computed by adding or subtracting the given number from the current value of the property.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.add-case', function() {
  $('.filling').animate({
    height: '+=40'
  }, 600);
});
```

```css
.filling {
  height: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filling"></div>

<button class="add-case">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was indeed the use of (this). Changed it to `$('.filling')` and it works.

Comment: If more than one element in jq matched set and each one with different height, this would give wrong behaviour

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "this", try getting the object by its id or class. As shown here:

https://jsfiddle.net/HimeshS/y1cqsovg/

```
 $('.filling').animate({ height: $(".filling").height() + 40}, 600);
```

If you are using this, it may be giving document object.